# .NET's equivalent of Java's MemoryImageSource

Tags: c#, java, .net, graphics, memoryimagesource

I found a wonderful open source Java program that I'm translating into C#. The built-in translator in Visual Studio got me started and I've now spent about a month translating the rest manually line by line. I've completed over 15,000 lines of translation and the only thing that remains is trying to figure out how to convert their MemoryImageSource stuff into C#/.NET.

What's the .NET equivalent way of implementing this stuff? Is there a native .NET library already?

Comment: Just curious, what's the java library that impressed you so much?

Comment: There's nothing about the Java library proper that I care for. There is just a program that happens to be be written in Java that I really dig.

Comment: `MemoryImageSource` itself isn't used much nowadays, since the more versatile `BufferedImage` was introduced in Java 1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard .NET [`System.Drawing.`**`Bitmap`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class in the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly comes close to what I know of the `MemoryImageSource` (i.e., an image represented as an array of pixels that you can manipulate).

For better performance, you can use the [`ImageTraverser`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageTraverser.aspx?display=Print) class from CodeProject, which accessses the array through unmanaged pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the System.Drawing namespace. This wraps the standard windows GDI+ native code.

System.Drawing.BitMap is probably what you want.